# How to move photos from Google Drive to Google Photos?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I have a lot of photos in Google Drive, in random folders.

I want to move them to Google Photos, because I really like the phone/tablet application - while the web app is... less good.

I have no idea how to do that. I moved them to some magical folder in Google Drive called "Google Photos". I have no idea what that folder does - it seems to be auto-synced with Google Photos in  the way Google Photos app -> Google Photos folder, but not the other way (folder -> app) - nothing I put there appears in the actual Google Photos app.

How do I put the photos there? There are both in Google Drive, I can see both "Google Photos" and my old photos in Google Drive web app, but I cannot move them there no matter how much I try.

edit:

In [this confusing help article](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en) which makes the relation between Google Drive and Google Photos even less clear, Google tells me to click on "search" and then "Google Drive". That produces "No results" on both android app and web app.

Comment: Googling the question around seems impossible because something about Google+ seems popping up, I am not using Google+ at all

Comment: This seems to be still the case. I was wondering if the "No results" on the Google Drive search was because I was using google apps for business but a customer support rep told me this simply doesn't work and will be removed. Looking at google photos now, the button seems to be gone. Still no option to sync between drive -> photos

Comment: As of 2018, the Google help article now mentions in the "See photos & videos from Google Drive in Google Photos" to turn on the Google Drive option from Google Photos settings

Comment: Google recently added a tool to Google Photos to import photos from Drive: https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103

Comment: Why do you want that?  Do you really want to share all of your pictures with the whole universe?  Google Drive has the only reasonable way to share pictures, even that the correct settings are difficult to find, because the default always is to include the whole universe.  But in Drive you CAN share in private, while in Photos everything you share is publicly shared to anybody who gets access to a very very very very short link.

Comment: This is a question from 2015, but still. I like Google Photos more for handling pictures than Google Drive. I know that sharing inside GPhotos is not "private" but come on, once I share something in GDrive the other user can copy it and share it himself too. So who cares.

Answer (score 47):

While on [**Google Photos**](https://photos.google.com/) **click Upload**, (probably upper right corner), then **click "Google Drive"**. If for some reason that didn't work, just [read this short official Google help made to answer this exact question](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103), it will tell you what's wrong.

If after clicking upload "google drive" doesn't show up, [It's probably because your account is work/school](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103). One workaround is to share the photos to a non-educational account, and follow the method given at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Damn it... Google messed it up again.

Comment: No Google Drive there.  Just "Computer".

Comment: +1. The question-asker should mark this as the best answer.

Comment: Does not import all a directory at once as far as I could try. I can just select picture by picture: this is just crazy from Google not to be able to move all Google Photo directory to Photo...

Comment: @MacKentoch How many directories do you have? All the pictures inside one directory? Or a few directories? Because in those cases, there is an easy workaround: just do what the answer suggests, when the upload pop up appears, select "my drive" tab, then go to the directory you want to upload its pictures, open it, and then select ALL the pictures inside of it (you do that by clicking on one picture and then ctrl+a), then just click on upload, and done!

Comment: To upload all images on your drive, after you click on "Google Drive" as described by @Santropedro then click in the search bar. In the drop down menu click file type then click "Images". Now you should be able to ctrl-a to select all the images and then click "UPLOAD" in the bottom right-hand corner. Do the same for videos too.

Comment: The best answer so far in 2019!

Comment: Like @Tino, I only see 'Computer' under 'Upload' - no 'Google Drive' option.  Tried chrome & firefox, linux & windows.  I have not determined why some people might see the 'Google Drive' option and others not.

Comment: @Juan Your problem seems notorious enough to "ask a question". I suggest you do it, there doesn't seem to be the answer here in stack exchange. So I think it will get upvoted eventually. You should include screenshots. Also, put in that question if you have installed Google Drive for Windows (or for Linux) the application. Also, if you used to see that option before. And put a picture in google drive today and wait some days to see if it appears.

Comment: @Santropedro, I did some google help forum diving, and it seems (at least anecdotally) related to G Suite accounts or possibly legacy accounts that are now (in 2019) called G Suite accounts (e.g., used to be 'Google App' at one point). That information that I saw was all anecdotal, but it agrees with my circumstances. As much of Google's tools go, the existence and explanation of edge case quirks is not public info. Maybe they know about them, maybe they don't. Maybe they'll apply fixes or not. Maybe they'll just delete the whole tool tomorrow. Or re-spin it and we get a new set of issues.

Comment: @Juan Ah great, your comment sheds a light. I would have NEVER guessed that. I haven't purchased or used in any way G suite. (That's one of the reasons, of me never having this problem). Good research.  You could report to google, you just click report, and they sometimes look into that specially if it comes from a G suite user, or get customer support. Thank you for your research! (please don't reply to this comment, this comment section is getting too cluttered)

Comment: -1 doesn’t solve the problem. He simply suggest you to go to the folders and press ctrl+a. Will be an issue if you have a lot of subfolders which most do, op as well

Comment: @jubibanna maybe I can answer your problem to earn back the upvote? Just in google photos, click upload, then google drive, then click on "my drive" and find the folder or picture you want. Or where is the file you want to upload located?

Comment: @Santropedro Not the person you're replying to, but regardless: that doesn't help since it only allows uploading one folder at a time, if you have multiple nested folders, you have to do each individually which is tedious at best.

Comment: @JSLavertu Thank you, Yes, now I actually understand what the original problem you guys had. I did research to see how to solve it: You can't directly do it with Google Drive Products or Google Photos, instead you must Google Search "flatten directory structure", those results will tell you how to put all the files (in this case pictures) in one big folder. Then you can upload it by following my answer! You will need "backup and sync" for Windows (or Mac, Linux, etc) to HAVE the folders in your hard drive so you can "flatten the directory".

Comment: @Santropedro Much appreciated! It's rather dissapointing that google doesn't natively offer a solution though...

Comment: Good research to figure out the caveat that this doesn't work for Work/School accounts (eg, G Suite, Google Workspace, whatever name they may give it in the future).

Answer (score 26):

1. Login to Google Drive
2. Click on the Settings button ([image: Settings button])
3. Select Settings
4. Make sure **Create a Google Photos folder — Automatically put your Google Photos into a folder in My Drive** is checked. 
   [image: Create a Google Photos folder]
5. Find and select the image you want to move.
6. Click on the Actions button ([image: Actions button]), and click on **Move To...**
   [image: Move To...]
7. Select **Google Photos**
   [image: Google Photos button]
8. Click on the [image: Move button] button.
9. Your photo has now been moved from Google Drive to Google Photos

Side note: If you want to go the opposite direction (Photos → Drive), then login to Drive, select Google Photos on the left side, select the picture(s) you want to move, click the action button → move, and select the Drive folder to move to.

Comment: For whatever reason (maybe my old experiments?), my folder "Google Photos" in drive contains entirely different photos than what is actually in Google Photos. Moving photos there does not move them to Google Photos. When I renamed the fake "Google Photos" folder to "Fake Google Photos", it renamed and I don't get another "Google Photos" folder, even with the settings turned on (and I turned it off, reloaded, turned it on).

Comment: @KarelBílek, I have no idea. I wonder what would happen though if you created compete new folder instead of renaming, moved the Fake photos into the new one. Then delete what is now the Fake Photos folder. Turn the option off and then turn it back on. I know Google doesn't really care what the names of files are folders, it assigns them a unique ID and goes by that. You can actually have two files or folders with the exact same name in the same folder. I have had that particular issue before with my text message backups.

Comment: Everything uploaded via Google Drive takes up quota space. https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103 Google Photos 'Recover Storage' specifically excludes Google Drive. https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6314648 The only official way to upload to Google Photos "High Quality"/free tier is with the Backup and Sync app. There may be unofficial options. https://github.com/3846masa/upload-gphotos Older Picasa API-based alternatives are slowly failing, such as no video. https://github.com/jackpal/picasawebuploader

Comment: What happens after this?  Does it take a while for the photos to get imported and appear in photos.google.com or the photos app?

Comment: Does moving an entire folder with subfolders work (as in do the photos later appear in photos.google), or just individual images?

Comment: It simply doesn't work. It's not clear why this is even an option if it doesn't do anything.

Comment: This does not do anything. Maybe it worked in 2017, but does not work in 2018. I get the same results as @KarelBílek

Comment: I checked too- There is no option to Move to Google Photos

Comment: This answer is obsolete since google stopped syncing photos and drive, see my answer below.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Please downvote, or #Drew Chapin should revise the answer to upvote.

Answer (score 25):

The only way I found, which is *super stupid* and as anti-user-friendly as they go (I guess that's the new Google), is to

- download the files (it will take a while, will create a big ZIP file and might crash the Google Drive app)
- *unzip them*, because while Google Drive gives you zip, Google Photos doesn't allow ZIP (output of an app is not accepted in basically the same app, awesome)
- upload to Google Photos, hope that it will actually upload and not crash in the middle
- then you will end up with the photos in both places, so you will need to delete one so it doesn't count twice to your quota

Not a good user experience. But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Google now offers a tool to upload photos from your hard drive: https://photos.google.com/apps

You can use the Google Drive application to download all your photos in drive, then use the Google Photos Backup app to upload them all to Google Photos.

Comment: The newer answer below (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106152/162414) is now a better way to do this.

Comment: @jfritz42 That answer does not work.

Comment: This answer is massively impractical compared to the current OFFICIAL correct answer I provided below.

Comment: @Santropedro sorry, I asked and replied this in 2015. I will try your answer later today.

Comment: Related, but unhelpful. HEIC photos is the download format for google photos, but can't be used in google slides.

Comment: New answer below! https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132183/139613

Comment: I don't have time to evaluate all the answers now :((((( it's several year old question at this point

Answer (score 2):

Seems it has moved to drive.google.com->settings
[image: Google Drive Settings screenshot]

Comment: Adding a screenshot or a Google help link would be more helpful.

Comment: I don't seem to have this option

Comment: I don't have this option either

Comment: this is exactly the other way around (“Automatically put your **Google Photos into a folder in My Drive**”). OP wants to move photos from Drive to Photos.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @törzsmókus, the integration shown in this answer seems to be gone anyway as of the July 2019 public announcement (see the answer from Santropedro posted on July 26, 2019).  Since this answer today is overcome by events and no longer an available option.

Comment: +1 I don't have this option