# Compress images uploaded through Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I moved a folder from Google Drive to Photos using [this process](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106152) and now I want to compress the size using the [Recover Storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87134/168477) feature. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to take effect for photos uploaded through Drive, even though they're now in Photos. Is there some way to make this work other than downloading and re-uploading all those files?